# broken pipe error when adding footer-html parameter to PDFKit (wkhtmltopdf)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, pdfkit

I am attempting to add a footer to a PDF I am creating in RoR 3.2.11 with PDFKit using the below code:

```
template = File.read "#{Rails.root}/app/views/layouts/portfolio.haml"
@ci = self
pdf_html = Haml::Engine.new(template).render self

template_footer = File.read "#{Rails.root}/app/views/layouts/portfolio_footer.haml"
@ci = self
pdf_footer_html = Haml::Engine.new(template_footer).render self

pdfkit_instance = PDFKit.new(pdf_html, :orientation => 'Landscape', 'footer-html' => pdf_footer_html)

send_data(pdf.to_pdf, :filename => "generated.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf')
```

Unfortunately this is causing a "Broken Pipe" error:

```
pdfkit (0.5.2) lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb:65:in `write'
pdfkit (0.5.2) lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb:65:in `puts'
pdfkit (0.5.2) lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb:65:in `block in to_pdf'
pdfkit (0.5.2) lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb:64:in `popen'
pdfkit (0.5.2) lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb:64:in `to_pdf'
app/controllers/admin/collection_items_controller.rb:9:in `test_generate_pdf'
```

When I generate the PDF without the footer it is successful. Its also successful if I use the footer html as the main html source. Using one of the plain text options like 'footer-right' will work too, but obviously I want to use the html option. This behavior is consistent both locally and when deployed to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

```
pdfkit_instance = PDFKit.new(pdf_html, :orientation => 'Landscape', :footer_html => pdf_footer_html)
```